# Searching for keyword combinations in pandas dataframe for classification

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up question to [Searching for certain keywords in pandas dataframe for classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432455/searching-for-certain-keywords-in-pandas-dataframe-for-classification/74432823?noredirect=1#comment131404718_74432823).

I have a list of keywords based on which I want to categorize the job description. Here are input file, example keywords and code

```
job_description
Managing engineer is responsible for
This job entails assisting to
Engineer is required the execute
Pilot should be able to control
Customer specialist advices
Different cases brought by human resources department


cat_dict = {
    "manager": ["manager", "president", "management", "managing"],
    "assistant": ["assistant", "assisting", "customer specialist"],
    "engineer": ["engineer", "engineering", "scientist", "architect"],
    "HR": ["human resources"]
}

def classify(desc):
    for cat, lst in cat_dict.items():
        if any(x in desc.lower() for x in lst):
            return cat

df['classification'] = df["job_description"].apply(classify)
```

The code works well if there is a single word e.g. "mamanger" or "assistant" but cannot identify the cases when there two words e.g. "customer specialist" or "human resources"

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a comma in your cat_dict dictionary. I tried your example:

```
import pandas as pd

cat_dict = {
    "manager": ["manager", "president", "management", "managing"],
    "assistant": ["assistant", "assisting", "customer specialist"],
    "engineer": ["engineer", "engineering", "scientist", "architect"],
    "HR": ["human resources"]
}

def classify(desc):
    for cat, lst in cat_dict.items():
        if any(x in desc.lower() for x in lst):
            return cat

text_df = pd.Series(text.split('\n')[1:])
text_df.apply(classify)
```

Result:

```
0      manager
1    assistant
2     engineer
3         None
4    assistant
5           HR
dtype: object
```

which successfully classified assistant for "customer specialist" and HR for "human resources".